# My PC doesn't sleep on suspend (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: system-installation, suspend, 19.04, standby

I have a problem with the suspend option on my ubuntu 19.04 setup. When on suspend fans and other components still stays on. I actually want my entire PC to go in sleep mode the same way it does when I used windows. How can I fix that issue?

Thanks

Comment: I've used boxes that have fans controlled by the motherboard as well as by OS; so if temperature is high and the machine suspends, the fans stay pn being controlled by the motherboard logic. In most cases the fans will slow down & turn off as the temperature drops below threshold.  Do the fans soon go quiet/slow as machine cools?

Comment: No It doesn't, I left it for 3hours and hust noticed fans didn't stop when I came back. On windows It did immediately stop though. My PC does not overheat, some components just do not sleep,